# Python Scheduled task does not write to file

Tags: python

I have created a Scheduled Task on Windows 7 to run a Python Script which will write a string to a file.

To test this, I created the following Python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

f = open("output.txt", "w")

f.write("hello")
f.close()
```

The script was saved in the directory: C:\Users\NeonFlash\Desktop\files\ with the filename: test.py

The Scheduled Task was configured as:

```
Program to Run: "C:\Python27\python.exe"
Program Arguments: "C:\Users\NeonFlash\Desktop\files\test.py"
```

When the scheduled task runs, it does not create the file.

I even selected the option "Run with highest privileges" for the scheduled task.

Below is the output of net user command:

```
User accounts for \\NeonFlash-PC

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            Guest                    NeonFlash
The command completed successfully.
```

When the script is run directly from command prompt, it successfully creates the output file. The issue occurs only when it is launched using a Scheduled Task.

Comment: If you open up Task Scheduler, you should see a column (I think on far right) called "Last Result".  What is the code in this field after it runs?  If it is anything but 0, there was an error.  I think whatever code is there holds information about what type of error it was.  Let me know if it is something other than 0.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is the working directory of your python is different when it is run by the task scheduler, the output file is in another folder you just have to find it ...just did a search, the default is the system32 folder, find your output.txt there.

this is what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

f = open("C:\\Users\\NeonFlash\\Desktop\\files\\output.txt", "w")

f.write("hello")
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Also, I had to escape the path. Replace "\" with "\\" in the file path.

Comment: right awesome, changed my answer to reflect that :)